# Why can't I use default interface implementation in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have two interfaces for a simple observer pattern:

```cs
// ObserverPattern.cs
public interface Observer<E>
{
    void OnFire(E e);
}

public interface Subject<E>
{
    List<Observer<E>> Observers { get; set; }

    void AddObserver(Observer<E> observer)
    {
        Observers.Add(observer);
    }

    void Fire(E e)
    {
        foreach (var t in Observers)
        {
            t.OnFire(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And two classes that implement this interface:

```cs
// CharacterObserver.cs
public enum Event {
    Action,
    Normal,
    Skill,
    Burst
}

public class CharacterSubject : Subject<Event>
{
    public List<Observer<Event>> Observers { get; set; } = new();
}

public class CharacterObserver : Observer<Event>
{
    public void OnFire(Event e)
    {
        switch (e)
        {
            case Event.Action:
                Console.WriteLine("Action!");
                break;
            case Event.Normal:
                break;
            case Event.Skill:
                break;
            case Event.Burst:
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(e), e, null);
        }
    }
}
```

However trying to call AddObserver or Fire on a CharacterSubject doesn't work:

```cs
CharacterSubject subject = new CharacterSubject();
subject.AddObserver(new CharacterObserver());
subject.Fire(Event.Action);
```

It only works when I reimplement AddObservers or Fire in CharacterObserver (either with the default implementations or without them). Why is it that I can't call those methods despite it satisfying the interface requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Default method implementations for an interface (provided a concrete class doesn't implement it) can only be accessed via the interface reference. So you need to declare your variable that interface if you wish to call it.

```
Subject<Event> subject = new CharacterSubject();
subject.AddObserver(new CharacterObserver());
subject.Fire(Event.Action);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not *really* treating your variable subject as an interface. If you want to use the implementations given by the interface, you should change the type of *subject* to be `Subject<Event>` to get the implementations, otherwise it will look for the overridden implementations specific to the CharacterSubject class!